# Having issues with numeric functions and formatting in my XSL doc, and names and percentages are not showing up in result doc

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been stuck on this assignment for weeks and I think that I fixed the majority of issues (please point them out if necessary). I am finishing an XSL doc that was mostly finished by the text book authors and it is linked to a pre-made XML doc that displays candidate names, vote counts, percentages, party's and districts. The page renders mostly correct except that the names of the candidates, districts, parties (D or R) and vote percentages (the percentages appear as **NaN**) are missing. Other than that, it looks fine and validates.

The "candidatePercent" variable contains the percent of votes assigned to the candidate, calculated by dividing "candidateVotes" by "totalVotes". Here is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="($candidateVotes) div count($totalVotes)" />
```

And in the "drawCells" template, it says to make the "cellCount" parameter equal to the value of "candidatePercent" multiplied by 100 and rounded to the nearest integer. Here is my code:

```
<xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="100 * round($candidatePercent)" />
```

Here is the full style sheet for reference:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="candidateInfo" 
    select="/candidates/candidate" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>
            <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="vwlogo.png" alt="Voter Web" />
               </header>

               <h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>

               <section id="votingResults">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="congressResults/district" />
               </section>

             </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="district">
      <h2>District <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></h2>
      <table class="electionTable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Candidate</th>
               <th>Votes</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate" />
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="candidate">
        <xsl:variable name="candidateVotes" select="sum(votes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="sum(..//votes)" />
            <xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="($candidateVotes) div count($totalVotes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateName" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/name" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateParty" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/party" />
      <tr>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="$candidateName" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="$candidateParty" />)
        </th>
        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($candidateVotes, '###,##0')" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="format-number(ScandidatePercent, '#0.0%')" />)
        </th>y
        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
            <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="100 * round($candidatePercent)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$candidateParty" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="drawCells">
      <xsl:param name="cellCount" />
      <xsl:param name="party" />
      <xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0">
         <td class="{$party}"></td>
         <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
            <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$party" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML document (created by the textbook authors):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<candidates>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL1">
      <name>Sanchez, Onita</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL2">
      <name>Berk, Thomas</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL3">
      <name>Thomas, Howard</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL4">
      <name>Sweet, Alice</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL5">
      <name>Aitkens, Mary</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL6">
      <name>Nielsen, Kevin</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL7">
      <name>Pulaski, Stewart</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="DFL8">
      <name>Venn, Michael</name>
      <party>D</party>
   </candidate>

   <candidate candidateID="REP1">
      <name>Troutman, Rachel</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP2">
      <name>Chiang, Michael</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP3">
      <name>Olsen, Fred</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP4">
      <name>Grovener, Stewart</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP5">
      <name>Mundleberg, Linda</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP6">
      <name>Francis, Trevor</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP7">
      <name>Biersen, Nancy</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="REP8">
      <name>Ramirez, Juan</name>
      <party>R</party>
   </candidate>

   <candidate candidateID="IND1">
      <name>Whitman, Gary</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND2">
      <name>Larson, Alicia</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND3">
      <name>Shapiro, Douglas</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND4">
      <name>Reardin, Samuel</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND5">
      <name>Ketrick, Rachel</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND6">
      <name>Inglessohn, Ray</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND7">
      <name>Pope, Richard</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="IND8">
      <name>Zander, Audry</name>
      <party>I</party>
   </candidate>

   <candidate candidateID="WI1">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI2">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI3">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI4">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI5">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI6">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI7">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>
   <candidate candidateID="WI8">
      <name>Other</name>
      <party>O</party>
   </candidate>

</candidates>
```

[Source Document (congress.xml) for reference](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awxrf8iu5g3fv32/congress.xml?dl=0)

Thank you.

Comment: You've got a global variable which can only make sense if `candidates` is the root element, and you've got a template for `district` which can only make sense if `candidates` is a child of `district`. Without seeing your source document, we can't tell which one is wrong, but they can't both be right.

Comment: @MichaelKay 
I see. The assignment told me to create the candidates global variable, and then I created the variables in the candidate template and called the drawCells template and its parameters. I have updated the post with a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/awxrf8iu5g3fv32/congress.xml?dl=0) to the source document. Thank you.

Comment: (1) Please make the Q self-contained. Data on external sites, especially drop-box, tends to be transient, while this question will be here in ten years time and should make sense on its own. (2) A stylesheet that works with "candidates" as root element isn't going to work (in general) with the richer congress.xml source document: I'm not sure now which one you are targeting.

Comment: @MichaelKay 

I understand, but I had to link it since it is well over the character-limit, sadly. The "congress.xml" is the result doc that I load/process using a Web browser, so that is the one I am targeting. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I actually figured it out (and other errors), with some help, of course.

First of all, I missed that I had a capital "S" here `

```
  (<xsl:value-of select="format-number(ScandidatePercent, '#0.0%')" />)
```

instead of "$". Secondly, I should have removed the "count" from

```
<xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="($candidateVotes) div count($totalVotes)" />
    `
```

I also failed to stick with the **document()** function in for the global variable. I assumed that since I almost finished it last week with only the path, it would have worked without. TLDR; pay more attention, use better glasses, do not make things out to be more complicated...

I appreciate the help regardless!